# RegExp /\c/ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

RegExp `/\c/` doesn't trigger any syntax error.

```js
console.log(/\c/)
```

The question is why it's not a syntax error. Since the language spec, I'm guessing `Pattern` → `Disjunction` → `Alternative` → `Term` → `Atom` → `\ AtomEscape` → `CharacterEscape` → `IdentityEscape`, then it arrives at `SourceCharacter but not c` and it doesn't match by the condition `but not c`.

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-regular-expressions-patterns

I wonder if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm thinking that's interpreted as an empty control character. `\cX` where   X is a letter from A - Z.

Comment: Hmm, but `c ControlLetter` doesn't have `opt` sign.

Comment: Everythink in between `/everythink/` will printable....! why?

Comment: JS engines are more lenient than the spec for regular expressions (unless there’s some part of the spec I’m missing). `/\c/` matches the literal text `\c`, just like other invalid escapes (`/\x/.test('\\x')`, `/\q/.test('\\q')`).

Comment: Annex B defines the "more lenient" spec.In the Annex B spec, `/\x/` is valid syntax, but `/\c/` looks not valid. So I wrote this question.

Comment: Oh, neat. So it looks like there is a mistake, then.

Comment: It also says: "When parsing using the following grammar, each alternative is considered only if previous production alternatives do not match." Doesn't that explain your case?

Comment: I think no. The alternative which matches to `\c` doesn't exist. Though if there is an alphabet at after `\c` then it's `c ControlLetter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.

The `\c` doesn't match to `\ AtomEscape` alternative. This was correct. So the `\` letter matches to `ExtendedPatternCharacter` and the `c` letter matches to `ExtendedPatternCharacter` individually.

```
/^\x$/.test("x") //→ true
/^\c$/.test("c") //→ false
/^\c$/.test("\\c") //→ true
```

Comment: This may have been true at the time, but today ExtendedPatternCharacter does not include "\" and instead ExtendedAtom includes the explicit alternative "\ [lookahead = c]". The effect is the same, though.

It’s worth noting that this is specific to the Annex B extensions, and even with Annex B, reaching this alternative is suppressed when the 'u' (unicode) flag is present and instead you’ll get a SyntaxError. To some extent, the u flag acts like "strict mode for RegExp".